# Setting up mysql DB for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We are new to the AWS and would really appreciate some help and guidance.

1. What is the RDS maintenance window/Back up window mean? 
   Our concern is: During the time range, our web server(@EC2) cannot access our RDS instance?
2. What is the best practice to set up mysql for EC2 instance?
   Is it stupid to set up mysql @EC2 instance with attached Provisioned IOPS( 10 GB/100 IOPS)? :)

   Our main concern is the performance. We know we should test it by ourselves. But it is also appreciated if someone could share experiences regarding how to set up mysql for EC2 instance.
3. What is EBS volume? Is it the Provisioned IOPS type when I click 'Create Volume'?

Comment: in general, it's better to ask one question per post

Answer (score 0):

1. You will be able to access during a backup window, maybe at somewhat decreased performance.  A maintenance window only occur if you made a change that requires a restart to apply, or in rare cases, an upgrade is required. Your instance will be down momentarily during such a case.
2. You probably don't need provisioned IOPS at that size. Instead use multiple volumes in a software raid configuration.
3. Think of it as a NAS volume. While it can only be attached to one instance, it is accessed over a shared network interface.

Comment: thank you for answer. I just found EBS stands for ELASTIC BLOCK STORE. So, it seems RDS based mysql will be faster than the EBS based mysql, right?  The only concern now is the maintenance window. Because there might be a customer who is placing an order, but error happened due to maintenance window. How can I avoid that? Use EBS based mysql instead?

Comment: Under the covers, RDS also uses EBS to store data. But its very difficult to engineer a database system that will have no downtime. But with good planning, you can keep downtime to a minimum.